# javac "uses unchecked or unsafe operations" when the type is being specified

Tags: java, types, interface, casting

The following code:

```
public void addGrillaListener(Stage stageToClose,Grilla listener)
{
    GrillaHandler<WindowEvent> handy = new GrillaHandler<>(listener);
    if(stageToClose!=null)
    {
        stageToClose.addEventHandler(WindowEvent.WINDOW_HIDDEN,handy);
    }
}
```

causes the compiler to show that message. How can I avoid it?

Extra info:

- Grilla is a Stage interface
- GrillaHandler is a EventHandler subclass that takes a Grilla as a constructor parameter
- Using JDK 7, GrillaHandler<> is allowed
- The compiler message is rather unespecific - it states that this method uses unchecked or  unsafe operations
- Stage is a class provided by oracle, it's part of javafx

GrillaHandler:

```
public class GrillaHandler<T> implements EventHandler {

    private Grilla win;

    public GrillaHandler(Grilla win) {
        this.win=win;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(Event t) {
        win.loadTable();
    }
}
```

Grilla:

```
public interface Grilla { 
    public void loadTable();
}
```

Comment: Shows the message at which line?

Comment: For me it appears the problem is in the parameter `Stage stageToClose`. It looks like this is a parameterized type so that it can later accept event handlers of a specific type. But it's not evident in your code. Can you post the definitions of `Stage` and `Grilla`?

Comment: GrillaHandler<WindowEvent> handy = new GrillaHandler<WindowEvent>(listener);

Comment: @Deepak It is no longer necessary to declare the type in the initialization if its the same as the declaration. I think this from JDK 7 onwards.

Comment: You can add the @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") annotation to the method and the message will go away.

Comment: @Thihara who says Alvaro is using JDK 7?

Comment: @DiegoLEspiñeira Yes, let's just suppress all warnings without investigating them.

Comment: @xagyg If he weren't, he'd be getting a compiler error, not a warning.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for the explanation. So what line is the warning occurring on?

Comment: @PaulBellora I thaught he knew why the compiler outputs the message and he wanted to suppress it anyways. So much for an attitude. We definitelly need more code to analyze that. We need Stage, Grilla and GrillaHandler definitions.

Comment: What is `WindowEvent.WINDOW_HIDDEN`? Based on the `addEventHandler` documentation, it must be an `EventType`, which is a parameterized type - is `WindowEvent.WINDOW_HIDDEN` a raw type?

Comment: @PaulBellora If this is JavaFx, according to [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/stage/WindowEvent.html) it is `EventType<WindowEvent>`, isn't i?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Yeah, you're right. So the call looks fine...

Comment: @PaulBellora I think the problem is that `javafx.EventHandler` is a parameterized type and no type argument is given in the declaration of `GrillaHandler`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change code to

```
public class GrillaHandler<T extends Event> implements EventHandler<T>{ 
//...
}
```

The JavaFX [EventHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/event/EventHandler.html) is a paremeterized type. You are missing that one in your declaration of the `GrillaHandler`. You are forced to provide a type argument in your class declaration or redeclare the type parameter, as you seem to require as per your declaration.

Comment: Niceeeee! I'm trying this later